# Make a method run in a method java for my game?

Tags: java

I'm struggling with dealing of inventory scan for my game, it basically search for the user inventory if "Flying Broom" if present(it was collected in another method and upload the code is too long), if not it will run the method challengedragon() again; else, it will proceed to the next challenge if the item is present.I was think of inserting method as parameter but it is not possible. This is what I have now. :

```
public class Main {

    String Flyingbroom = "Flying broom";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player_inventory p = new Player_inventory();
        challengedragon();
    }

public void challengedragon() {


    System.out.println("a Hungarian Horntail dragon! Let's start the battle! You have four options to beat the dragon: ");
    System.out.println("1: Fly away with your broom");
    System.out.println("2: Fight the dragon");
    System.out.println("3: Just run to the egg and get it");
    System.out.println("4: Hide behind a rock");
    System.out.println("5: Go back to Hogwart");



    System.out.println("Your choice is: ");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dragonfightchoice = in .nextInt();

    if (dragonfightchoice == 1) {
      {
        p.Scanitem(Flyingbroom,
          "Good choice! You managed to kill the Hungarian Horntail dragon and to get the golden egg",
          "You dont have the broom. Try to search for the broom",
          playerHP);
        proceedtonextchallengelake();

      } else if (dragonfightchoice == 2) {
        System.out.println("The Hungarian Horntail dragon fired you. - 70HP. ");
        playerHP -= 70;
        challengedragon();
      } else if (dragonfightchoice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Bad idea... You lose 100 HP");
        playerHP -= 100;
        challengedragon();
      } else if (dragonfightchoice == 4) {
        System.out.println("The dragon found you. You lose 30 HP");
        playerHP -= 30;
        challengedragon();
      } else if (dragonfightchoice == 5) {
        Hogwart();
      } else {
        invalid();
        challengedragon();
      }
    }
```

For my inventory class:

```
public void Scanitem(String item, String trueouputext, String textifconditionisnotmet) {

        if (inv.contains(item) == true) {
            System.out.println(trueouputext);

        } else if (inv.contains(item) == false) {
            System.out.println(textifconditionisnotmet);
        }

public static ArrayList<String> inv = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Do you guys have any recommendation?

Comment: I would recommend to use a switch statement instead of that many else-if.

Comment: I am agree with @AndiCover. user  switch in place of if else. I didn't see any problem in code. better give more explanation.

Comment: Well Yes . No! Sit back and think about what you realy want. The big complete picture. Most likely you end up with the questions("Attack options" - or what  else)  dependend on a situation: who(swordfighter archer, mage), meets whom(dragon, superman ...) in which place(can't run if in prison / can't climb a tree if there is none...) and which state(eg. XP ) and so on. So you most probably end up with some generated(due to factors) actions maybe also weighting(taking the first as default).. Meaning you will put your questions in some datastructure. Probably that will void the whole question;)

Answer (score 1):

Are there additional steps to populate the inventory (variable `inv`)?

Also, wouldn't you want ScanItem to answer true or false, depending on whether the item was found?  Then you would have something like this:

```
public boolean scanitem(String item) {
    return ( inv.contains(item) );
}

if ( p.scanItem(flyingBroom) ) {
    System.out.println("Good choice! You managed to kill the Hungarian Horntail dragon and to get the golden egg");
} else {
    System.out.println("You dont have the broom. Try to search for the broom");
}
```

That will get you closer to what you want.  However, there are two other issues which you'll need to put into your code:

You will need a loop of some sort, instead of calling `challengeDragon` from inside of itself.

Somehow, the return value from scanItem must be used to decide whether to loop.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you do a nested call of a method each time the player does something, this means that sooner or later you'll run out of the stack. A better idea for the framework for your text-based adventure is to have some kind of a description of the current game's state. The state could be represented as an object that contains the following information:

- where's the player currently at (on which step, at which "crossing" etc.)
- the player's stats (HP, available skills etc.)
- the contents of the player's inventory
- some previously made choices affecting the game

Then, the code could be written as a simple loop that does the following:

- process player's input
- change the state according to the player's input
- present the player with available options according to the new state
- wait for the next input
- repeat